# IDEA warns about using curly braces in JavaScript regexps. Is it ok?

Tags: javascript, regex, intellij-idea

Inside a *.js file I use the following pattern to find a string contains 4 digits:

```
value.match(/\d{4}/)
```

Chrome eats it correctly, but Intellij IDEA 12.1.4 shows a warning on the closing '}' (actually it underlines it without a comment).

[image: screenshot]

Is usage of {} in such regexps unwanted in some way or it's just a bug of IDEA?

Comment: Using `{}` as quantifiers is definitely fine.

Comment: Interesting - can you post more code? `function(value, element)` is a syntax error, I guess there must be something before this.

Comment: There was no error - just an ordinary anonymous function.

Comment: Hm, can't reproduce that. No highlighting here. Does it say anything when you press Show Intentions (alt+enter)?

Answer (score 3):

known issue. Please vote for [this ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6717)